# PivotTable: Filter out pivotitems less than a date variable

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a dynamic table in which I have the day filter which comes from the =DAY() function and I want to be able to filter it from visual for days less than or equal to the present day.

I can filter the information but I get error 13 type mismatch

```
Sub TablaZona2()
Dim pvtItm1 As PivotItem
Dim fecha As Integer
Dim PTable1 As PivotTable



Set PTable1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TablaZona1")

fecha = Day(Now)


For Each pvtItm1 In PTable1.PivotFields("DIA").PivotItems

If pvtItm1.Value < fecha Then
pvtItm1.Visible = True
Else
pvtItm1.Visible = False
End If

Next


End Sub
```